# I don't understand why my layout doesn't show

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm new to .NET programming and I'm having trouble applying a Shared Layout to a blog page.

My project contains the following files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snByx.png)

I've created a file named _Layout in the Shared folder, which contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Blog.css")" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Mon Blog ASP.NET MVC</h1>
        <ul id="navliste">
            <li class="premier"><a href="/Accueil/" id="courant">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Accueil/About/">A Propos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="corps">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>@DateTime.Now.Year - Mon Blog MVC</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file Blog.css contains the following code:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #FBF9EF;
    padding: 0px 6%;
}

header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #5D5A53;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

    header h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        float: left;
        padding: 45px 0px 5px 0px;
    }

ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px dotted #5D5A53;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* barre de navigation header */

ul#navliste {
    float: right;
}

    ul#navliste li {
        display: inline;
    }

        ul#navliste li a {
            border-left: 1px dotted #8A8575;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            color: #8A8575;
            text-decoration: none;
            float: left;
        }

        ul#navliste li:first-child a {
            border: none;
        }

        ul#navliste li a:hover {
            color: #F6855E;
        }

/* fin barre de navigation header*/

p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h2 {
    color: #5e5b54;
}

header h1 a {
    color: #5E5B54;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #F6855E;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:active {
    color: #006633;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I'm trying to display the Index view from the Accueil folder, which contains the following code.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
```

Unfortunately, the previously defined layout isn't being applied, and I only see the text of the _Layout file but without the style of the Blog.css,

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `F12` to see if any error in the console tab.
it shows:
[image]

If you want to  serve Blog.css outside of web root, want it in the Content folder, you can try to add  access the  Blog.css file by configuring the Static File Middleware in Program.cs as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Content")),
    RequestPath = "/Content"
});
```

result:

[image]
**Note** If you don't add the Layout in the ViewStart , remember add the layout in the Index like:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
```

**Or** try to add Blog.css into the wwwroot css folder , then change below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Blog.css")" type="text/css" />
```

into:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Blog.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple layouts, i think this could help you:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Page Title";
}
```